# Django only loads base.html

Tags: django

I'm trying to learn Django and am trying to setup a user login system. My site only shows the base.html contents, and not the contents of login.html. If I remove the extends base.html, the login form seems to show up correctly. Am I doing something wrong?

login.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load url from future %}

{% block content %}

{% if form.errors %}
<p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
{% endif %}

<form method="post" action="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
<table>
<tr>
    <td>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>{{ form.password.label_tag }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.password }}</td>
</tr>
</table>

<input type="submit" value="login" />
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

base.html

```
 <body>
    <div>
      {{ user }}
      {% if user.is_anonymous %}
      <a href="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}">login</a>
      {% else %}
      <a href="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout' %}">logout</a>
      {% endif %}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `base.html` template is missing a corresponding `{% block content %}{% endblock content %}` and also a closing `</body>` tag. There's nowhere for the content in `login.html` to go.

Answer (score 0):

Brandon is right.

you can think {%block content %} as a hole in your base.html and the extended file only replace/fill in that hole.